# How to call specific @WebMethod in WebService in JAVA?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jax-rs

Consider the publisher :

```
package rand;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class RandPublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String url = "http://localhost:8000/rs";
        System.out.println("Publishing RandService at endpoint " + url);
        Endpoint.publish(url, new RandService());
    }
}
```

And the WebService with its webmethods :

```
package rand;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import java.util.Random;

@WebService
public class RandService {
    private static final int maxRands = 16;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetNextOne")
    public int next1() {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetNext")
    public int[] nextN(final int n) {
        final int k = (n > maxRands) ? maxRands : Math.abs(n);
        int[] rands = new int[k];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            rands[i] = r.nextInt();
        return rands;
    }
}
```

1.How can I call a specific webmewthod from the Browser ? 
I've tried :

http://localhost:8000/rs/GetNextOne?wsdl

But it doesn't do anything ...

2.How can I call `nextN` (AKA `GetNext`)  and pass a param to that webmethod and consume it ?

Comment: How is it related to [[tag:rest]] or [[tag:jax-rs]]?

Comment: This is not JAX-RS, it is JAX-WS, which is messaging based on XML and SOAP. You need to send a properly formed SOAP request, which typically has a request body containing XML.